# Cross Sells are not being shown in Cart Page. Please Help!

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using " Consulting Theme" on Wordpress but the problem is I've linked my product cross-sells but they're not showing up on Cart Page. Can anyone help me with what I need to do to show them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below scenario.

Review below path(Theme folder path) file

themes/consulting/inc/woocommerce_configuration.php

Hide this 5th line
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display' );

it's working fine. Review below screenshot https://ibb.co/c9o24T

Comment: No, I haven't added them to cart. Please help. If there's any plugin to display them would help too.

Comment: @AnirudhPulikonda
please provide your theme  full name & URL.

Comment: URL: http://consulting.stylemixthemes.com and theme name: Consulting

Comment: @AnirudhPulikonda
Review below path(Theme folder path) file
themes/consulting/inc/woocommerce_configuration.php 

Hide this 5th line
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display' );

Comment: @AnirudhPulikonda
It's working fine. Review below screenshot 
https://ibb.co/c9o24T

Comment: @AnirudhPulikonda Review updated answer

Comment: You're really awesome. Thanks for the solution. Worked like a charm. BTW, One small question - You debugged everything relating to this issue from the theme demo page itself?

Comment: I have download the theme then reviewed then fixed the issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80985/discussion-between-vinothraja-and-anirudh-pulikonda).